# Find area of the triangle ABC, given the coordinates of vertices in plane

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, triangles, area

> $A, B$ and $C$ are the points $(7,3), (-4,1)$ and $(-3,-2)$ respectively. Find the area of the triangle $ABC$.

I've worked out the lengths of each side of the triangle which are $AB=5\sqrt5$, $BC=\sqrt10$ and $AC=5\sqrt5$.

I know that the formula for the area of a triangle is $\frac12hb$ but when I checked the solutions the answer to the area of this triangle is $17\frac12$.

I do not understand how this answer is achieved.

Comment: Every heard of the [Shoelace formula](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj98ZbnuLzPAhVS8mMKHR9sCtAQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FShoelace_formula&usg=AFQjCNGNUIPcP8vUMSPH4WQFF4LEvSdrOg&bvm=bv.134495766,d.cGc)?

Comment: Another way would also be to draw a rectangle around the triangle and subtract each section not included in the triangle, but you would need the graph for that.

Comment: Fine comments above. Still another way is to exploit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem

Comment: OP; stop changing it. it's fine.

Comment: In order to not to waste your efforts, you may just apply Heron's formula to the computed side lengths, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Follow-through**

As you have said before, the side lengths of $\triangle ABC$ is $AB=AC=5\sqrt{5}$, $BC=\sqrt{10}$, using Heron's formula, we can compute the answer.

Heron's formula states that given side lengths $a,b,c$ of $\triangle ABC$, the area is given $$\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}\tag{1}$$
Where $s$ Is the semi perimeter. ($s=\frac {a+b+c}{2}$).

So in your case, we have $$a=5\sqrt{5},b=5\sqrt{5},c=\sqrt{10}\tag{2}$$
The semi perimeter is $$\frac {10\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{10}}{2}\tag{3}$$ and plugging in the values, we have $$\sqrt{\frac {10\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{10}}{2}\left(\frac {10\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{10}}{2}-5\sqrt{5}\right)\left(\frac {10\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{10}}{2}-5\sqrt{5}\right)\left(\frac {10\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{10}}{2}-\sqrt{10}\right)}=\boxed{17.5}\tag{4}$$

Comment: I understand this now but how would I type this into a calculator to get the correct result ? Thanks.

Comment: @Dan Hm... If I were to have to solve the messy radicals, I would first write it out, and then break down the parts. So I would first calculate what $\frac {10\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{10}}{2}-5\sqrt{5}$ is, then $\frac {10\sqrt{5}+\sqrt{10}}{2}-\sqrt{10}$ and so on...

Comment: @Dan Also, note that on a calculator, if you press Alpha, then Y= and 1, then you get the option to write your fractions in $\frac ab$ form. Much more neater that way.

Comment: @Frank - "on a calculator..." ?? Not on mine. I think you have made a generalization here that does not apply to many many calculators.

Comment: @MichaelKaras A standard TI-84+ calculator is able to do it. And I believe a standard TI-83 calculator is capable of doing that too. Unless I have mistaken for which type of calculator he used..

Comment: @Frank - Still a guessing game. Dan just said "type this into a calculator". Be aware that there is no such thing as a "standard calculator". The only thing that could even come close to that might be the ubiquitous simple "four banger" calculators that just do +-*/ functions.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Okay, well I'm just gonna assume that Dan has a graphing calculator. They're really nice. You should really get one. :)

Comment: @Frank - I've been in engineering for 47 years and never had need for a graphing calculator. These days my needs are met by software that is on the computers I sit behind every day. The closest I ever got to a graphing calculator was walking by them in the aisle at the store and the one time I was required to buy one for a daughter that was taking a class where such device was "required". The required equipment when I was taking my engineering and physics courses was a slide ruler. You know what that is?

Comment: There are more companies than TI that build calculators.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Many of my classes *required* graphing calculators. Even if you don't have one, you can always get a functionally equivalent simulation online. If graphing calculators didn't exist when you took classes, it's obvious you wouldn't have used them. I'm sure you had lots of fun looking up trig results in a large lookup table.

Comment: Even if the OP uses a graphing calculator, they should show their work on paper anyway. It's good practice and helps you notice mistakes, should you make any.

Answer (score 13):

Since you have obtained the length of each side, using Heron's Formula is a natural way to find the area.  Let's consider the approach suomynonA suggested in the comments. Consider the figure below.

[image: triangle_inscribed_in_a_rectangle]

We can find the area of $\triangle ABC$ by subtracting the sum of the areas of the three right triangles $ABD$, $ACF$, and $BCE$ from the area of rectangle $ADEF$.  I will leave the details of the calculations to you.

Answer (score 7):

**Method-1**
$$\Delta= \frac12\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 &   1\\ 
x_2& y_2 &  1\\ 
 x_3& y_3 &  1
\end{vmatrix}$$
**Method-2**
This can also be used to find the area of polygon.
$$\Delta= \frac12\begin{vmatrix}
x_1 & y_1 \\ 
x_2& y_2 \\ 
 x_3& y_3 \\
x_1 &y_1
\end{vmatrix}=\frac12\left ((x_1y_2+x_2y_3+x_3y_1)-(x_2y_1+x_3y_2+x_1y_3)\right)$$

Answer (score 6):

You can use $BC$ as the base and measure the height with respect to it as the distance from a point to a line. If the line has equation $ax+by+c=0$, then the distance from the point $(x_0,y_0)$ to the line is
$$
\frac{|ax_0+by_0+c|}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}
$$

The line $BC$ has equation
$$
\frac{y-1}{-2-1}=\frac{x+4}{-3+4}
$$
or, in simplified form,
$$
3x+y+11=0
$$
The distance from $A$ to the line $BC$ is
$$
\frac{|3\cdot7+3+11|}{\sqrt{3^2+1^2}}=\frac{35}{\sqrt{10}}
$$
Thus the area is
$$
\frac{1}{2}\cdot\sqrt{10}\cdot\frac{35}{\sqrt{10}}=\frac{35}{2}=17+\frac{1}{2}
$$

Actually, there is a much simpler formula when one of the points is the origin. Suppose you want to determine the area of the triangle $OBC$, where $B(x_1,y_1)$ and $C(x_2,y_2)$. The line passing through $B$ and $C$ has equation
$$
(y_1-y_2)(x-x_2)-(x_1-x_2)(y-y_2)=0
$$
or, in simplified form,
$$
(y_1-y_2)x-(x_1-x_2)y+x_1y_2-x_2y_1=0
$$
By the above formula, the distance from $O$ to the line is obtained by using $x_0=0$ and $y_0=0$, so it is
$$
\frac{|x_1y_2-x_2y_1|}{\sqrt{(y_1-y_2)^2+(x_1-x_2)^2}}
$$
and at the denominator you recognize the length of $BC$, so the area is
$$
\frac{1}{2}|x_1y_2-x_2y_1|=
\frac{1}{2}
\left|
\det\begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 \\ y_1 & y_2 \end{bmatrix}
\right|
$$
Well, your triangle can be seen as having the origin as one of its vertices, by the translation mapping $A$ to the origin! The new coordinates of $B$ and $C$ in the translated frame of reference are
$$
(-4-7,1-3)=(-11,-2)
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
(-3-7,-2-3)=(-10,-5)
$$
so the area is
$$
\frac{1}{2}
\left|
\det\begin{bmatrix} -11 & -10 \\ -2 & -5 \end{bmatrix}
\right|=\frac{1}{2}\lvert-55+20\rvert=\frac{35}{2}
$$

In general, by implicitly doing the translation, the area of the triangle with vertices in $(x_0,y_0)$, $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ can be computed as
$$
\frac{1}{2}
\left|
\det\begin{bmatrix} x_1-x_0 & x_2-x_0 \\ y_1-y_0 & y_2-y_0 \end{bmatrix}
\right|
$$

Answer (score 4):

When you have all three side lengths of a triangle then you can use *Heron's formula* to find the area:

$A=\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$, where $s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$

Answer (score 4):

You considered using the formula $\text{area} = \frac{1}{2}(\text{height})(\text{base})$ here. While there are more specialized methods to this case, the approach you thought up works perfectly fine.

You just have to select a side to be the base, and compute the base and height lengths.

e.g. if you pick side $AB$ to be the base, you've already determined that it has length $5 \sqrt{5}$.

So to finish the problem, you need to find the height — that is, the distance from the line $AB$ to the point $C$. There are a number of ways to go about this, and the value turns out to be $7/\sqrt{5}$.

Thus, the area is $\frac{1}{2} \cdot (5 \sqrt{5}) \cdot \frac{7}{\sqrt{5}} = \frac{35}{2}$.

Comment: This is wonderful, could you tell me a simple way to calculate the distance from the line AB to the point C please?  I was seeing the diagram from N. F. Taussig's answer and thought BE is the distance you were referring to.  But BE is only 3 units in the diagram.

Comment: In this case, you've proved that the triangle is isosceles, so it's easier to use  BC as the base.  Then the height is just the distance from A to the midpoint of BC, since the altitude and the median coincide.

Answer (score -1):

I need anwer .A(6,2),B(2,4) and C(8,-4) are three in a plane in the line BC and Q is a point in the plane, such that PAQB is a rectangle. Find the (I) equation of the sides AP and BP. (ii) the coordinate of the points P (iii) the area of the rectangle

Comment: To ask a new question use the "ask question" button. If you do, you should also explain what you have tried, why can't you solve it.